# NameError: name 'user' is not defined; class related I think

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I am trying to create a battle function for a simple text based adventure game. We haven't covered classes yet in class but after doing some searching, it seemed the best way to do it. However, I keep getting a NameError: name 'user' is not defined.

Here is the code so far, I have been searching and searching and I just don't quite get where it's wrong.

```
import sys
import random
import time

number = random.randint(0,20)


class user:


    def __init__ (self, player_name, player_health, health_potion):

        self.__player_health = player_health
        self.__player_name = player_name
        self.__health_potion = health_potion

        def getName(self):
            return self.__player_name

        def getHealth(self):
            return self.__player_health

        def getPotion(self):
            return self.__health_potion

        def setHealth(self):
            self.__player_health = 100

        def minusHealth(self, number):
            self.__player_health -= number
            return self.__player_health

        def minusPotion(self):
            self.__health_potion -= 1
            return self.__health_potion

        def plusPotion(self, number1):
            self.__health_potion += number1

        def plusHealth(self):
            self.__player_health += 20



    def fight(soldier, player1, name1):

        player1 = user(name1, player1.getHealth(), player1.getPotion())
        soldier = user('Soldier', soldier.getHealth(), soldier.getPotion())

        p = 0
        while p == 0:
            time.sleep(2)
            attack = input("1 = Attack with weapon, 2 = use potion")

            if attack == "1":

                time.sleep(1)
                print("You strike at your enemy. Soldier's health now is", soldier.minusHealth(number))
                print("Soldier hits you back and your health is now at", player1.minusHealth(number))

            elif attack == "2":

                time.sleep(1)
                print("You use a first aid-kit!")
                player1.plusHealth(), player1.minusPotion()

                if player1.getHealth() > 100:

                    player1.setHealth()
                    print("Soldier hits you back and your health is now at", player.minusHealth(number))

            elif enemy.getHealth() <= 0:

                    print("You have won the fight!")
                    s = 2


    def main():
        name1 = input("What would you like your player to be named?")
        time.sleep(1)

        player1 = user(name1, 100, 0)
        soldier = user('Soldier', 80, 0)

        print("Your characters stats are: Health:", player1.getHealth())
        time.sleep(2)

        soldier.setHealth(80)

        fight(soldier, player1, name1)

        booty1 = input("Type ' 1 ' to loot the enemy")
        if booty1 == "1":
            print("You find two first-aid kits")
            player1.__plusPotion(2)

    main()
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not a problem with your indentation? You have the main code inside your class. Try taking it out.

Comment: By convention, most capitalize the name of a class. So it would be `class User(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main is indented like a class method

unindent main call and definition

Comment: This worked, but now i'm getting the following error:
`code`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kensai/Desktop/lab3/project/fight.py", line 99, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/kensai/Desktop/lab3/project/fight.py", line 87, in main
    print("Your characters stats are: Health:", player1.getHealth())
AttributeError: 'user' object has no attribute 'getHealth'

Comment: same indentation error - pull all methods between fight and init to the left

Comment: To make sure it's clear, take from getName() to getHealth() and dedent it so it's in the class. Then dedent everything below as well so it's in the main code